# Character Models: Single Mesh vs. Individual Parts

Tags: game-design, 3d-meshes, character

I was looking up 3D character models from various games (Battlefield 3 and DMC to be specific), just as research work and upon importing the model into Blender3D, I found that every part of the model was a separate mesh/object (head, armor vest, legs, hands, etc.).

This got me thinking: Why didn't the artist model them as a single object?

I think that would be better because:

1. You can save a few polygons in your model [*].
2. Doesn't animating separate parts [**] cause clipping issues as one mesh may not deform in sync with neighboring mesh?

[*] All parts were overlapping each other = the armor vest was overlapping chest polygons, which were not visible and thus wasted.

[**] All polygons and edges connected to each other.

Answer (score 4):

One central reason would be that in order to assign different materials, you need different entities / meshes / sub-objects. You don't need to have an individual object for each minor element (such as the mouth or the lips of a head) if you are applying a texture later, but UV unwrapping a few not so complex object separately and applying then a material is easier than UV unwrapping a single high-complex mesh.

Also: The polygon count is not a really relevant statistic anymore in contemporary 3D. Batchable draw operations are usually much more crucial to prevent unnecessary drawcalls / state switches. See the following extract from the [Unity Graphics Performance](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html) page:

> Typical bottlenecks and ways to check for them:
>
> 1. GPU is often limited by **fillrate** or memory bandwidth. Does running the game at lower display resolution make it faster? If so, you’re most likely limited by fillrate on the GPU.
> 2. CPU is often limited by the number of things that need to be rendered, also known as “**draw calls**”. Check “draw calls” in [Rendering Statistics](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderingStatistics.html) window; if it’s more than several thousand (for PCs) or several hundred (for mobile), then you might want to optimize the object count.

Regarding animation: It depends on what kind of animation one is using: If you are working with a deformation approach (think "[Armature](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Armature)" in Blender terms or "[morph-target animation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morph_target_animation)" or "vertex blending animation" in general) than a single object should work. But for bone based approaches individual objects make handling it usually easier.